# Suppress google-chrome-stable console log in Linux Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am using **google-chrome-stable** to generate PDFs inside a linux docker conatiner. I start the process from a C# program (**.NET 7.0**)
No matter what I do, I can't get the console output to turn off. I tried to redirect the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` as well as adding `2>&1` to the argument list.
My code looks like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process chromeProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
chromeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
chromeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
chromeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
chromeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => { };
chromeProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => { };
chromeProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
chromeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "google-chrome-stable";
chromeProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"--headless --no-sandbox --print-to-pdf=\"{PdfPath}\" \"{HtmlPath}\" 2>&1";
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    chromeProcess.Start();
    chromeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    chromeProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    chromeProcess.WaitForExit();
});
```

Comment: I think you only need one dash in this case and not two for names of parameters.